# How to pop / finish a view in Windows Phone 7

Tags: navigation, windows-phone

I'm new to the Silverlight development stack in WP7 and have a need to blow away a view as I'm loading another.

```
//some good stuff happens so I need to load the next activity/view
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Checkout.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But just before/or after this navigation I need to pop/finish the current activity

In Android I would call finish and in objective-c I would simply pop this view controller from the stack ... but in WP7 I'm not sure how to remove this activity

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can finish off whatever you're doing in the [Page.OnNavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) handler, if you really need to. But I think you should explain what kind of logic you're wanting to end. Async operations in other threads require a cancellation token to be dismissed, and UI rendering operations will end automatically when you change the view.

But **remember** that WP7 uses a back button, and thus keeps a navigation state. Meaning that the user expects to be able to press back, to return to the previous view, and having it look precisely like it was when they left it.

--

Flow of how it normally would pan out:

```
App.xaml

  - MainPage.xaml (Your initial view)

     IF (UserIsLoggedIn)
        - Display Content
     ELSE
        - NavigateService.Navigate(new Uri("/Login.xaml"))

   - Login.xaml

     IF (LoginComplected)
         NavigateService.GoBack()
     ELSE
         DisplayError
```

Comment: agreed- but I'm in need of this behavior because I will be removing a login activity and if the users hit back they could login again causing pain for me :)

Comment: how in this event could I kill the previous activity on the stack?

Comment: You can't "kill" a view. Your approach for handling the login here is wrong. The right solution is to navigate to the login view if login is necessary, and upon completion of the login, use the NavigationService.GoBack() , so the user is returned to the main view of the application. That way, the view is removed from the navigation state.

Also, it's not called a "activity" for WP7dev. It's a Android-only name (and a bad one!) Call it a view or page instead, and everybody will understand you ;-)

Comment: Understood - I can adapt to the style you mentioned. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear- I was using this approach to keep the user from being confused.

With the WP7 approach I've added a simple MessageBox to let the user know the login was valid before going back so they are aware that the login was legit :)

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("","Login Successful!", MessageBoxButton.OK);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();  
            }
```

Comment: While it's a decent solution, I'm yet to see any other apps that behaves like that. Most simply leaves the login-screen when they're done. From a mobile UX perspective, the user expects things to work, and only be informed when it doesn't work. So this to some users might seem like a pointless annoyance ;-)